# how to move camra to a specific marker in google maps v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am able to display a marker as well as showing it with zoom and camera setting when first time user is viewing the map. But my requirement is to move the camera to same marker position(when user want) if user goes away from that marker position(marker gets off-screen) during his/her visit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for replies,
but i was looking for some native Map component to perform the map marker reset task rather than an external button to navigate back to desired marker location. I got this working with the latest update in Map Api(to have setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener) Using below code:-

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng markerLoc=new LatLng(companyDetail.getLatitude(), companyDetail.getLongitude());
    final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(markerLoc)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
    .zoom(13)                   // Sets the zoom
    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
    .build();                   //
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(companyDetail.getLatitude(), companyDetail.getLongitude())).title("Marker"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: those who aren't getting it,
it's `.target(marker.getPosition()) `

Answer (score 25):

Having a reference to the GoogleMap object and to the Marker, you can simply use

```
GoogleMap mMap;
Marker mMarker;

[...]

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMarker.getPosition(), 14));
```

(where you would substitute the "14" for your desired level of zoom).

Just attach that line to the OnClick event of the button that the user will click to "get back" to the marker... and you're done! ;)

Answer (score 7):

you can use [animateCamera][1] function of GoogleMap object

```
GoogleMap googleMap = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#animateCamera%28com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate%29
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like this :

```
LatLng cur_Latlng=new LatLng(21.0000,78.0000); // giving your marker to zoom to your location area.
gm.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cur_Latlng));
gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4));
```

//  another method is to use current location

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 4);

gm.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

Marker myMarkerthirtyfour = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

.position(latLng)

.title("You are here") 

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }
```